# Точка с запятой — знак препинания?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, точка-с-запятой

Является ли точка с запятой знаком препинания?

Насколько я знаю, данный знак препинания — если он таковым считается — употребляется только в сложных бессоюзных предложениях. Примечание: про употребление этого знака препинания в типографике мы не будем говорить, ибо меня это не интересует.

Например, я придумал такое предложение: «Моя мама, кстати, немка; люблю немцев». Предложение придумано чисто для примера (не воспринимайте это в качестве правды). В данном предложении, как я понял, имеем две грамматические основы: [Мама немка] и односоставное предложение [люблю]. Правильно ли оформлено предложение?

И вот кое-что мне ещё интересно. Точка — это знак препинания. Так, понятно. Её функция — заканчивать предложение, в котором не выражен ни вопрос, ни какое-либо чувство, например радость или досада. Точка имеет одну-единственную функцию. У другого знака препинания (например, у запятой) функций гораздо больше (на мой взгляд, у неё самое колоссальное количество функций. Сколько там условий употребления запятой!).

Так вот. Итак, сложное бессоюзное предложение — это одно предложение, следовательно, знаки препинания не создают в нём новое предложение. В придуманном мною предложении точка с запятой разделяет два предложения, ага.

Извините, я просто не могу выразить свою мысль корректно. Точнее, не могу сформулировать свой вопрос.

А нет, давайте всё-таки попробую.

Есть два предложения:

1. «Моя мама, кстати, немка. Люблю немцев». В этом случае имеем два отдельных предложения (причём каждое является простым).
2. «Моя мама, кстати, немка; люблю немцев». В данном случае у нас одно сложное бессоюзное предложение, так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Является ли точка с запятой знаком препинания?

В таких и им подобных сомнительных случаях обычно обращаются к словарям. [Извольте убедиться](http://dic.academic.ru/searchall.php?SWord=%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D1%81+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9&from=ru&to=xx&submitFormSearch=%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8&stype=0) - помогает! Ну, если случай такой серьезный - можете к бабке сходить...

> Насколько я знаю, данный знак препинания — если он таковым считается — употребляется только в сложных бессоюзных предложениях.

Сфера употребления точки с запятой не ограничивается бессоюзными предложениями. Позвольте предложить Вашему вниманию исчерпывающий, насколько мой неискушенный ум может судить, [список](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/?rub=tz) случаев постановки этого знака.

Единственное, что мне неясно, - в чем цель Ваших поисков. Вы хотите выяснить, могут ли простые предложения объединяться в бессоюзные, между частями которых ставится точка с запятой, безусловно и беспрепятственно?

Answer (score 1):

Странный вопрос... Почему же не является?

> > В данном предложении, как я понял, имеем две грамматические основы: [Мама немка] и односоставное предложение [люблю]. Правильно ли оформлено предложение?

Правильно. Но вторая основа - не односоставное, а определенно-личное.

Comment: Это не обувь, это туфли... (определенно-личное - вид односоставного предложения)

Answer (score 1):

Все правильно. Действительно, определенно-личное - вид односоставного предложения.

Comment: Это действительно бессоюзное сложное предложение?

Comment: Если нет союза между его частями, то действительно бессоюзное

Comment: Да, Инна права.

Comment: Подробнее здесь: http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/?rub=tz